# Resetar sequência todo ano

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu estou criando um identificador que tem a seguinte formatação `sequence/ano`, por esse motivo eu preciso que a minha sequence passe a contabilizar do 1, novamente, sempre que houver uma virada de ano.
Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso de forma automática ou terei que dropar e recriar a sequência todo ano manualmente?

Comment: Sem você mostrar um trecho de código ou qualquer coisa assim fica muito complicado te ajudar.

Comment: Mas eu não tenho dúvida num código que eu estou criando, eu quero saber se existe alguma maneira de eu resetar uma sequence do número que ela está para 1 toda vez que virar o ano...

Comment: Tem algumas idéias [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942844/how-do-i-automatically-reset-a-sequences-value-to-0-every-year-in-oracle-10g). Estão em inglês mas parece que não tem nenhuma resposta 100%

Comment: Cuidado ao usar sequences pois elas garantem unicidade mas não integridade , se uma numeração não pode ter falhas elas não são recomendadas.

Comment: Eu não preciso de integridade, só unicidade mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas versões inferiores a 12 você precisa setar a propriedade increment com o valor atual só que negativo e chamar o nextval para zerar o atual e voltar o increment para o padrão que você utiliza, assim "zerando" a sequence, exemplo:

```
declare
  ValorAtual integer;
begin
  select Seq_teste.NEXTVAL * -1 into ValorAtual from dual;
  execute immediate 'ALTER SEQUENCE Seq_teste INCREMENT BY '||to_Char(ValorAtual) || ' minvalue 0';
  execute immediate 'SELECT Seq_teste.NEXTVAL FROM dual' into ValorAtual;
  execute immediate 'ALTER SEQUENCE Seq_teste INCREMENT BY 1';
end;
```

Na versão 12 existe um comando para resetar as sequences:

```
alter sequence Seq_teste restart start with 1;
```

Para automatizar este processo, você pode criar um procedimento com o script necessário e criar um job agendado para rodar em toda virada de ano.

Comment: Mas daí não seria mais fácil criar um processo que, simplesmente, drop e crie de novo essa sequence todo ano?

Comment: É, apenas dei uma opção além de dropar e recriar a sequence, mas o nível de complexidade seria o mesmo. Para automatizar, no PLSQL puro não teria muito como fugir dos Jobs.